# blender 2.8 texture not showing up in nodes viewer and not updating in texture paint on change in nodes

Tags: node-editor, texture-painting

I am trying to load a mask image into Blender, process it right there (instead of doing it, for example, in Photoshop) and use as a mask in the texture paint. I create the new mask texture, go to the nodes, and do stuff like inverting and changing contrast. I think, this is a nice workflow because you do everything in Blender. However, there is something I cannot understand (by the way, for illustration, see the picture below).

[image]

1. The texture is not shown in the veiwer node or in the output node - that means that I can only see my changes when I switch to the texture paint.
2. The texture is not updated automatically in the texture slot on my brush. It does so only if I reload the texture to the slot. I guess, it is no problem to script an 'Update' button but, if this is bug, probably, it is worth reporting
3. Very irritating: when I switch to the node regime, it AUTOMATICALLY assigns 
   the texture to the TEXTURE (not MASK) slot of the active brush! That sucks as hell because, apart from updating the brush, you must also each time remove it from the texture slot (because I only want the mask slot). Ever worse: when you remove it from the texture slot, it clears the window of the node editor. It adds like + 100 % unnecessary job to my workflow.

Please, if you can resolve this, I would be grateful!

As a lyrical side-step - I think, Blender's texturing workflow could match that of the Substance Painter's easily just if it had a bit more adequate user interface. It is really very inconvenient, and it seems, noone really updated it for ages now. Don't want it to be abandoned like the game engine.

Comment: This is a feature that is not entirely working well even in 2.79b and I had thought it was actually being replaced later within the bounds of 'everything nodes'. I can confirm all that you have written happens here as well, so possibly this just needs to be written up as a bug report for now until they can either fix the behavior or modify the workflow some. One thing that would be great is for the Texture Mask to be able to be mapped to 3d as well as the Texture Brush.

Comment: @CraigDJones thank you for taking time! I will write the bug report. I think 'everything nodes' is not a bad paradigm, it just needs more polishing. and yes, it would be nice to have texture mask projected in 3d, and movable as a stencil (currenlty it is not). and it's also not so fine that the tiling in 'Tiled' regime scales when you change the brush size. Anyways, thanks for taking time

Comment: What do you mean that you can't move it in Stencil mapping? Alt-rmb is the legacy shortcut there, as rmb is for the brush texture stencil mapping move.The Tiling change of scale is because your brush texture is related to the brush size - it isn't independent, and for now is only unaffected by zoom when painting in the 2d image editor. Already put in a feature request on rightclickselect.com for that.

Comment: @CraigDJones indeed, alt-rmb works! thanks a lot! regarding the tiling, hope, it will be implemented soon

Comment: One thing that they might look at is that the node editor indicates only 'Brush' and might be why it is causing a problem when disconnecting to use as Brush Mask.

Comment: @CraigDJones exactly, i'll throw an update here as long as I post the bug report